# Linux Not Updating or Pinging To Internet (even after disabling ipv6)

Tags: apt, upgrade, sudo

Typing "sudo apt-get update" on the command-line gives a long string of "Failed to fetch..." errors, the last lines being:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried practically every solution I have seen on the internet, including:
- disabling IPv6
- uncommenting "precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100" in /etc/gai.conf
- typing `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf` on the command line
- forcing the server to use IPV4 with a new root file
- disabling the firewall on both my Kuri robot (whose system I'm SSHed into) and my computer
- including the Google DNS nameservers in the resolv.conf file
- disabling and enabling Network Connections in the System Settings
...,etc.

**edits**:
`cat /etc/resolv.conf` gave this output:

```
# Generated by Connection Manager  
search lan  
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

`ip addr` :

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:07:32:4c:4b:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.73.116.169/29 brd 10.73.116.175 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:07:32:4c:4b:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.150/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`ip route` :

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 
10.73.116.168/29 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.73.116.169 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.150 
192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  scope link
```

`ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
```

Observations and Notes:
- PING-ing ubuntu.com (or any other website, for that matter) gives a "hostname unknown" error on the terminal
- My laptop is connected to the internet to through an ethernet cable. I am able to access the internet in my web browser with the ethernet connection, so I have ruled out faulty ethernet connection. I SSHed into my robot through the WiFi. (NB: The WiFi does not provide internet connection, and is solely for SSHing into the robot, which is why I am using an ethernet to access the internet.)
- I'm eventually trying to install rosbridge and a ros-web-video-server on the robot, but this has been unsuccessful, probably for the same reasons as the above.

Comment: Is this issue happening on the kuri robot or on your laptop?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, I'm getting the issues on the robot, which i am operating from the terminal on my laptop (ie. I am SSHed into the robot).

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include: `cat /etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: May you also include the output of the following commands in your question
```ip addr```

```ip route```

Comment: All three edits now posted. :)

Comment: Between eth0 and wlan0, you're connecting to two different networks. Which is correct? Disconnect wlan0, and see what `ping 8.8.8.8` does, and `host www.ebay.com` does. Then reconnect wlan0 and unplug eth0 and retry the same commands. Also show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`. Report back. Use @heynnema in comments to me or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema My ethernet is for connection to the internet, while the wireless connection allows me to SSH into the robot. My understanding is that I'd need both to install packages during the update. (When I disconnected from the ethernet, 8.8.8.8 was "unreachable.")

Comment: Let's be clear... if you disconnect the wi-fi... does `ping 8.8.8.8` and `host www.ebay.com` work? If you reconnect wi-fi, and ssh into the robot, and try the same commands there, do these same commands work? In other words, is the problem on your host, or on the robot?

Comment: @heynnema The problem must definitely be from the robot. When I disconnect from the WiFi, I can't input commands into the terminal controlling the robot. When I connect to the WiFi and disconnect from my ethernet, ping 8.8.8.8 gives `destination net unreachable` on the robot terminal.     On the user terminal, ping 8.8.8.8 is successful when the ethernet is connected and the WiFi is disconnected. It is not succesful when the ethernet is disconnected. (The WiFi I'm using does not provide internet connection, but only allows for connection to the robot. :))

Comment: Was this working before and suddenly broke after a system update or has it never worked? If a system update broke the system what does `uname -r` reveal for current kernel version?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It has never worked. `uname -r` outputs the number `4.4.13`

Comment: Again, let's be clear... when on the host, not ssh into the robot, ping and host commands work, yes? When you ssh into the robot, in that terminal, those same commands fail, yes? How is the robot connected to the Internet?

Comment: @heynnema To your first two questions: exactly! I think I see what you're getting at: I'm guessing the robot is having troubles connecting to the internet -- which is what the ethernet on my laptop was for.

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way. The robot needs its own connection to the Internet. SSH is only for remoting into the robot. What is the robot used for?

Comment: @heynnema The robot is basically for a project. I'm trying to create a GUI which shows what the robot sees as it moves. I am using rosbridge, and I intend to use a rosbridge web video server to implement this visualization. Thank you for pointing out what you just did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your robot doesn't have access to the internet then it will not be able to update or ping anything on the internet.

You answered your own question when you said "(NB: The WiFi does not provide internet connection, and is solely for SSHing into the robot, which is why I am using an ethernet to access the internet.)"

Your computer having access to the internet over Ethernet doesn't do anything for the robot because they are two separate things. In your case, ssh is only giving you shell access on the robot, it isn't acting as a proxy or a gateway.

I found some documentation from the Kuri site that explains how the advanced features need to be run on a computer connected to the same network as the Kuri (which your computer is)

> The following steps have to be run from a development environment connected to the same network as Kuri. The following has been tested with recent versions of Firefox and Chrome.
>
> checkout the code:
>
> git clone https://github.com/KuriRobot/kuri-documentation
>
> run the local server
>
> cd kuri-documentation/examples/webrtc
>     python3 -m http.server
>
> open a browser window and point it to http://localhost:8000
>       get the UUID of your robot by running the following command on the robot
>
> roboversion - 
>   enter the hostname and the robot UUID in the webpage and click the Join button
>       you should see what the robot sees, and a text box will appear
>
> Extra steps: the rosbridge protocol
>
> The text box that appeared enables you to send commands and receive responses to and from the robot via the rosbridge protocol.

sounds to me like rosbridge should already be on the robot. If not, you should be able to download things to your laptop, then move them to the Kuri over SSH but with `scp`